# How to avoid timer stacking

Tags: c, timer, kernel, vibration

I'm sorry if his question has already been asked in some way.

I'm currently re-writing a vibration driver in a Linux kernel. The reason why I changed it was due to overly strong vibrations caused by gaining a specific velocity of the vibration motor. To work that around I've implemented a PWM like controller that simply stops the motor at a specific time before reaching it's max acceleration, finally it keeps repeating this action.

There is one big issue that is mainly noticeable when using the keyboard. If the vibrator gets toggled too often in a very short time, the timer tends to stack up times, causing lag and vibration delays. This flaw can be easily achieved when typing multiple keys at once.

To demonstrate you this event visually I created a small graph.

[image: Timer Graph]

The red area indicates timer overlap. The overlap between vibration 1 and 2 causes a delay for the second vibration, moving it out of place.

My main idea to prevent this issue is to merge vibrations into one if the previous vibration hasn't finished yet. For instance vibration 2 would simply join vibration 1.

Another way would be to simply use a single vibration for stacked vibrations, for instance, vibration 2 could simply use the last remaining bit of vibration 1. Why would this work? Well because the vibration controller that I've implemented only applies to times under 100ms, meaning vibration time differences would not be noticeable if one was to spam to keystrokes at once, instead both keystrokes should form and share single vibration.

Finally to my question, how could I make a function check itself it it's being called again. Or at least add a time for the function to check if keystrokes are being spammed multiple times in a short period?

Comment: Focus on one question derived from one problem. Don't give us unnecessary information, don't try to answer your questions, don't apology It's meaningless, make clear what you're asking, fix the typo, "almost perfectly" makes no sense it is either perfect or broken. It is obvious that it is not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

```
int foo ()
{
    static foo_counter;

    if(foo_counter)
    {
        // If function has been called again
    }

    return(0);
    foo_counter++;
}
```

Comment: I'm aware of the following method already, the problem with this is the fact that the function already gets executed once. What I'm looking for is something like a loop that checks if the function has been re-called in the let's say next 10ms. Ex: while (check != timeout){check for new function call}. Aka I want it to predict a function call, but if it doesn't arrive it continues doing what it's supposed to do

Comment: Well, check this function: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html

Comment: You don't "predict" you enter a function and inside the function decide (check) whether to force return or do its thing. Check the timer function it has routines to be destroyed